# Determine the remote MQ queue manager accessing our local queue

Tags: ibm-mq, mainframe, zos

i am trying to write a script that will - when passed an MQ queue name - indicate either 'end' of the queue i.e. who puts messages on and who takes them off.

To establish the manual method of doing this (before I automate it) I picked a QLOCAL at random and using CA-Sysview, I used the MQROBJ screen to see that one of our CICS regions PUTs messages on the queue and our MQ CHIN started task GETs messages off the queue.

But I can't see where the messages go. As this is a QLOCAL but it's the CHIN job taking messages off it, then I assume that some remote queue manager has this queue defined as a QREMOTE and is issuing GETs against the queue.

We have access to normal z/OS MQ commands and CA-Sysview

Can I establish the remote queue manager taking messages off the queue?

Comment: I don't think you can. Very curious to see if there is a way.

Comment: @SaggingRufus Does my interpretation seem correct? All the IBM docs & diagrams I find about using remote queues mamagers talk about remote queues and triggering. Putting messages on local queues and waiting for a GET from a remote QMGR seems not to be discussed.

Comment: What you describe is basically how I have seen things set up where I work. There are 2 queue, so if you were one putting the messages you would have a queue called XXX_TO_YYY and you may be using a queue manager called MQX1. This would be a local queue for you. When I go to get those messages, I would call a queue called YYY_FR_XXX which could be using a queue manager called MQY1. In this case, the queue I issue the GET to is local to me, and the queue you issue the PUT to is local to you, but your queue is remote to me and my queue is remote to you.

Comment: In this type of setup, I don't know if it possible to identify the remote queue or manager as this is all set up within the MQS config (as far as I know at least).

Answer (score 3):

In order to determine either end of the queue usage diagram, try the following command on your QLOCAL.

```
DISPLAY CONN(*) TYPE(ALL) ALL WHERE(OBJNAME EQ local-q-name)
```

and look for the following fields; `APPLTYPE`, `APPLTAG`, `OPENOPTS`, `CHANNEL`, `CONNAME`

You can tell whether the application is a putter or a getter by looking at the `OPENOPTS` field in the output. If it says `MQOO_OUTPUT` then it is a putter, and if it says `MQOO_INPUT_*` then it is a getter.

If the application has a `CHANNEL` name filled in, then the connection that is using that queue came down a channel. You must go to the machine described by the `CONNAME` and investigate further from there. You should be able to tell the difference between a client application and a sender/receiver channel by using the channel name.

If you are tracking a path across a sender/receiver channel, then on the remote machine you must take a look at QREMOTE definitions. Try a command like the following:-

```
DISPLAY QREMOTE(*) ALL WHERE(RNAME EQ local-q-name)
```

Comment: Morag - thanks. the command response is **MPO1 DISPLAY CONN(*) TYPE(ALL) ALL WHERE(OBJNAME EQ PPDAA1.APLUS.DRS.AUTOCASE.UPD)
  CSQM297I MPO1 CSQMDRTC NO CONN FOUND MATCHING REQUEST CRITERIA**. If I look at the 'MQ Request by Object; display in Sysvies (Sorrtty - I don;t know the z/OS command equivalent) the only connection types against that queue are CICS (for the PUTs) and CHIN (for the GETs);

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know if any remote machine is involved. I'm trying to find out if there is.

Comment: Try the `DIS CONN` command many times in a row.   Sometimes you will find a client app written that connects, gets,  disconnects, repeat.   On unix i can run the display in a while true loop and usually catch it,  not sure how to do the same on zOS.

Comment: @JoshMc thnks Josh - did try but never got a hit.

Comment: Another detail you can obtain is last put and get time.  The setting on the queue is `MONQ`.  It can be set to `QMGR` which means to take the value of the `QMGR MONQ` setting, or it can be set to `OFF` to turn collection off for that specific queue, or it can be set to `LOW/MEDIUM/HIGH` which in the words of the knowledge center "here is no distinction between the values LOW, MEDIUM, and HIGH. These values all turn data collection on, but do not affect the rate of collection."

Comment: One should not worry about CPU hit as MQ is collecting the information anyway and this setting just turns on if it is displayed or not, you can see this by the fact that when you enable it you will sent historic put/get times prior to it being turned on.  If `MONQ` is turned on with `LOW/MEDIUM/HIGH` then the command `DIS QS(PPDAA1.APLUS.DRS.AUTOCASE.UPD) MONITOR` will show you `LPUTDATE/LPUTTIME/LGETDATE/LGETTIME`.  The `LGETDATE/LGETTIME` should help you narrow down when you should be checking the `DIS CONN` output.

Comment: For instance if you note a pattern that it always gets on the hour, then run your continuous `DIS CONN` loop around that time to try and catch the GETer.

Comment: The DISPLAY CONN command will only show the connection if it is connected at that time. You say that you know it is the CHIN job getting the messages off - how do you know that? If it's a local queue, it's got to be a client channel. If it were going to be a sender channel then your queue would have to be an XmitQ.

Since you're on z/OS, you should see "Channel Started" and "Channel Stopped" messages for client channels in your JESLOG for the CHIN (unless you have suppressed them). Do you have a lot of client channels in your system?

Answer (score 0):

A remote queue manager does not "take messages off the queue". That's simply impossible. Since you mention z/OS, then there are patterns where shared queues may be involved, but that's more like a different local qmgr than a remote one.

The local CHIN will take messages off a queue to SEND it to a remote queue manager if it's defined as a transmission queue (USAGE=XMITQ) and there's an associated channel. And at that point you know what the remote qmgr is.

If the queue is not a transmission queue, then the only way a channel is involved is if there's a CLIENT application connected to your queue manager. And then, looking at QSTATUS and CHSTATUS ought to give information about what's doing the work.

More generally, there **are** ways to work out the path a message would take through an MQ network - research the dspmqrte command. Even if it is not part of the MQ on z/OS product, you can run it as a client application from another platform.

Comment: Mark - are you saying that you cannot issue a GET against a QREMOTE? This appears to be a normal QLOCAL - not a XMITQ and no INITQ or PROCESS defined. I can't see how CHSTATUS will help as I don't know which channel is involved. .If I issue QSTATUS for this queue what can I expect to see that will indicate where the messages are going?